# How to echo / embed laravel view output in layout as variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to use view helper like {{ render_part("user_profile"); }} in laravel layout, and render_profile will return and html,
Right now it prints as plain string and not rendering as HTML, Also I need some good guide to understand laravel blade/view compilation architecture so that i can write custom classes overriding core methods.

Comment: Why aren't you using blade `@include('view')` instead?

Comment: Yes exactly but i want to include subviews dynamically decided from controller, So i want to echo @include('viewname', $data) dynamically from controller to blade layout

Answer (score 3):

I've upvoted Gerard Reches answer. But if you want to render views from your controller and display the HTML in your views:

By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
{!! $myHTML !!}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great Thanks.. Still i want to send whole '{!! $myHTML !!}' as variable from controller, Possible ?

Comment: Sure, you'd have to render a view (and optionally pass on variables) within your controller. Something like this should work: `$html = view('your.view', ['foo' => 'bar'])->render();`. Add *$html* to the response and output it. Be sure to check out the docs on Laravel's views: https://laravel.com/docs/master/views. It's pretty well-written.